# Calculus of Variation with three variables

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a functional of following form,where u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z)and w(x,y,z) are three dimensional function.
$$\int \mathcal{L}(u,v,w,u_{x},u_{y},u_{z},v_{x},v_{y},v_{z},w_{x},w_{y},w_{z},x,y,z)\, dz$$

i want it to minimize for u,v,w

Then please let me know if  following euler equations are right or not....

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u} - \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{z}} \bigg) = 0
\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial v} - \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial v_{z}} \bigg) = 0
\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w} - \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w_{z}} \bigg) = 0
\end{aligned}

or Should it be in the following form
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u} - \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{x}}\bigg)-\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{y}} \bigg)-\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{z}}\bigg) = 0
\end{aligned}

Comment: Check this $$\int \mathcal{L}(u,v,w,u_{x},u_{y},u_{z},v_{x},v_{y},v_{z},w_{x},w_{y},w_{z},x,y,z)\, dz$$ I think there is something missing.

Comment: @nmasanta did you mean it should be triple(volume) integral...? but this problem has integral in third direction only. Although i  found euler equatoins would be of following form\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u} - \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{x}}\bigg)-\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} y} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{y}} \bigg)-\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z} \bigg( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{z}}\bigg) = 0
\end{aligned}But now i am facing problem in understanding the boundary conditions.